# Beginner of Node.js and MongoDB. I just wondering why there is no "isAdmin" in my MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Beginner of Node.js and MongoDB. I just wondering why there is no "isAdmin" in my MongoDB and how to fix it? Thank you~

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

The user at database is without "isAdmin" like this:

```json
username: "johnAdmin"
email: "johnAdmin@gmail.com"
password: "$2a$10$pjuVsWEe8BhP0nvgNcjS3eSp0vKwyzDUZNGDf5nYn3/Rn2yunh.iy"
createdAt: 2022-11-05T21:44:42.402+00:00
updatedAt: 2022-11-05T21:44:42.402+00:00
```

I have tried to change `"required"` to `true`, but it still does not work.

Comment: This is not MongoDB, it’s Mongoose. You need to review the docs for Mongoose. Set a default in your schema for it to show.

Comment: Yes, but I did set "isAdmin" in the UserSchema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default value for isAdmin

```
 isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
```

or

check while saving the user you have isAdmin field in the object

```
let user = User({
username: req.body.username,
email: req.body.email,
password: req.body.password,
isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin
})

user.save()
```